# Why does my code break going from Android Studio 1.3 to 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a working app in 1.3 that breaks when I tried to "upgrade" to 2.0.

I tried code clean up as some have suggested , deleted the R file and recreated as others have suggested.  This is the new error that is not present in 1.3 but shows up in 2.0 .

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.CardView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Any thoughts that you may have so I can use 2.0 would be appreciated.  For now I'm sticking with what works.

My list view is in a navigation drawer fragment.  There are no cardviews anywhere associated.  I have cards only in a recycler in another fragment.

For reference if it matters here's a piece of my build gradle for project and module

```
   buildscript {
    System.properties['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

// from build module

```
      minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'



    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.java-diff-utils:diffutils:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a solution:  I upgraded my project settings to gradle version 2.10.  I was at 2.4.  I also changed gradle build to 2.1,  I was at 2.0.  After making these changes it compiles and runs nicely in Studio 2.0.

My take away lesson is be careful not to assume that when your code breaks that you are the cause.  It may just be an artifact of an environment change or "upgrade".